# How to say "I will just let future me deal with it" in Japanese?

Tags: translation

「I will just let future me deal with it」は日本語で何と言いますか。

It's a part of my sakubun I'm currently writing and I just don't know how to say this sentence in Japanese? I'm thinking maybe:

> 未来の私それを対応するだろう。

but not so sure.

Comment: Welcome to Japanese Language! This site is not a translation service, we can help you if you try to translate it yourself first.

Comment: You're trying to say something really idiomatic. Do you have at least an attempt at saying it yourself? Something specific that confuses you? The question will be closed in its current form.

Comment: While I'm not certain what form of "future" to use (未来、将来、明日, something else...), I get the strong sense that 任せる is the verb you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is it that you want to let a future you deal with?  I ask mostly because 「[対応]{たいおう}」 is a fairly big word and it may be too big a word to go with whatever you are talking about if it is not very serious.

As always, the most natural phrases will not look anything like the English original.

> 「（そうなったらなったで、）その[時]{とき}に[自分]{じぶん}で[考]{かんが}えます（or 対応します）。」 or
>
> 「それはその時に自分で考えたいと思います（or 対応したいと[思]{おも}います）。」

Using 「考える」 would be far more natural than using 「対応する」　in the sentences above.

If you want your Japanese to "look" more like your English for some reason, you could say:

> 「それは[未来]{みらい}の[自分]{じぶん}に[判断]{はんだん}（or [解決]{かいけつ}）させたいと思います。」　自分 ＞ 私 ←Important

Finally, you could use what Kaji suggested above and say:

> 「それは未来の自分の判断に[任]{まか}せたいと思います。」